# Edit array in PHP file

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, delete-row

I have a small issue. Is there (in PHP) any way to update array **in the php file**?
For example I have file with this code

```
$array = array(
    'test' => 'aaaa'
    'test2' => 'aaaa'
    'test3' => 'aaaa'
     etc etc, more data
);
```

I load this array via include file.php using $array, I do some stuff and pick just few keys I need to delete (they are unused, ...).
Is there any way how to do it nicely?
I mean I could delete file and fwrite first line, then use foreach for every key and at the end write ); to file. But there is a problem. The file does not include just this array (There are multiple variables, texts,...).

So could anyone help me?
Please dont ask me why its done this way, Im not happy about it either, I just need to solve this.

Summary: **I have the array keys i want to delete in array + I have array in .php file I need to modify nicely**

Comment: Maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php is what You're looking for.

Comment: If you mean parsing and editing the source code of a PHP script of arbitrary structure, it's going to be difficult to come to a robust solution unless you go through the hassle of a full-fledged PHP code parser. Is it possible to change the code and just read the array values from a separate data file?

Comment: No its not possible. I just have to update this file. Thats all I can do.

Comment: I suppose it is not possible to seperate the "file.php" in multiple files. Well, Despite the array does the content change frequently? Does the file contain always the same variables? Can you post the content of file.php?

Comment: If you set up a clean array where after you work on it and alter the data into this new array, you can then save it as serialized data back into the file.  You're not stuck using the original array, clean and manipulate into a new one then save that new array back where the old array is in the same data format.

Comment: It changes, Thats bad about that. Is there any possibility to delete just that array from file and include there a new array (its possible to create new array) using var_export?

Comment: Well, as the other content changes you could write a FileHandler that has a queue and alters the file accordingly. However, therefor you need to know the existing variables and every script that alters the file needs to use this FileHandler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to store your *data* as *php array*, instead of some database then you should use: [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Then your workflow will look like:

1. Save your data **as serialized array** to a .php file.
2. Load it from there and **unserialize**.
3. Work on it.
4. If your work with the array is ended, **serialize and save** to the file again.